# Run MySql from Java failed

Tags: java, mysql, process, exec

I'm trying to run MySql command from Java process using Process exec

the code:

```
String s = "mysql -h192.168.0.1 -u USER -PASSWORD DB_NAME-e \"select * from table\"
System.out.println(s);
Process p = r.exec(s);
p.waitFor();
```

When I'm running the sql query from command line its works great, but from the Java process I get '
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]... with all the MySql options.

Without the -e parameter its seems to work, no error but of course nothing happens.
In Win& machine its also works great, not on the deploy Linux machine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Example of Java using MySQL:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

// assume that conn is an already created JDBC connection (see previous examples)

Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT foo FROM bar");

    // or alternatively, if you don't know ahead of time that
    // the query will be a SELECT...

    if (stmt.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar")) {
        rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    }

    // Now do something with the ResultSet ....
}
catch (SQLException ex){
    // handle any errors
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
finally {
    // it is a good idea to release
    // resources in a finally{} block
    // in reverse-order of their creation
    // if they are no-longer needed

    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { } // ignore

        rs = null;
    }

    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { } // ignore

        stmt = null;
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have lot of Java code connected to MySql. but now  need to yse axec sinnce I can't use java code to connect the DB

Answer (score 1):

Try this, see if it aids your efforts

http://pastebin.com/XpRyGQBq

Usage: 
                DBConnectionHandler | new DBConnectionHandler(connectionURL, username*, password*)
          ResultSet | +query(String sqlStatementGoesHere)
                     void | +update(String sqlStatementGoesHere)
                     ResultSet | +getTables()
*means optional

Comment: Thanks, But I need to use the MySql as external proc, not using java code.

Comment: You have referenced the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) right?

Comment: Sure, as I wrote if I remove the -e parameter its works, the error is not in the java code but in the Mysql command I assumed.